# Python / package source code

Tags: python

When I ctrl click a builtin function in my IDE I noticed I usually get sended to an init file which holds the function but it just returns the function again.. It states a vague doc string like 'original footprint unknown'

Where do I find the real functions ?

For example where is print_function

Comment: Possibly because this is a ridiculously vague question that barely makes sense and is impossible to answer in its current form.

Comment: I have tried several IDE whenever you click to see the source of a builtin you get redirected to a seemigly empty wrapper, how come

Comment: those are functions implemented in C typically, that are in some DLL or compiled extension somewhere

Comment: Really? Can anyone link me the location of this part of this part of python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the specific example, `print` is defined in C, in the `bltinmodule.c`:  specifically.

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Python/bltinmodule.c#l1518

More generally, functions implemented in C have no equivalent to the source file you would read in python; the C code is compiled into binary machine code, and no reference to where that bit of code might have come from is (usually) retained in the result; and even if there was, it's unlikely that you happen to have the source code installed in a place your IDE is likely to find it, unless you built it yourself, with debug symbols, and are running the C executable process in that ide's debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in the same directory where that file is. (Which I can't possibly know.)